# how to know array elements are perfectly centered?

Tags: java, arrays

`{3, 2, 10, 4, 1, 6, 9}` is perfectly centered array because `10+4+1=15` sequence is preceded and succeeded by same number of elements  i,e two.

```
  mid=arraylength/2;
    for(int i=0;i<arraylength;i++){
           int sum=a[mid]+a[mid+1+i]+a[mid-1-i];
           if(sum==15) break;
}
```

after calculating `sum=15`,how to know `10,4,1` is preceded and succeeded by same number of elements?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a perfectly centered array? With your definition, it seems like all arrays should be perfectly centered. Is it required for the center to have a sum equal to 15?

Comment: yeah it is required for the center to have 15 so 3 elements which give sum 15 is perfctly centered.

Comment: Is your scope to calculate if those values are equal 15 ?

Comment: 3+ 2+ 10 = 15, 1+ 6+ 9 = 15. Does this play a role, or is it random?

Comment: An array is called centered-15 if some consecutive sequence of elements of the array sum to 15 and this sequence is preceded and followed by the same number of elements.  For example 
{3, 2, 10, 4, 1, 6, 9} is centered-15 because  the sequence 10, 4, 1 sums to 15 and the sequence is preceded by two elements (3, 2) and followed by two elements(6,9).

Answer (score 0):

As I could understand, your scope is to check if a array of int is centered. For centered, you mean that the sum of the element in the center and the right/left one is equal to 15. You haven't to check if the number of reaming element is the same, because for an odd number of element, if you sub an odd number(3), you get an even number. (in this case the number of element are 7, the centered are 3 and the reaming are 4, 2 per side).
Here is the working code for your problem:

```
private static int SUM = 15;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int array[] = {3,2,10,4,1,6,9};
    if(calculateSum(array)==SUM){
        System.out.println("The array is centered");
    }else{
        System.out.println("The array is not centered");
    }

}

public static int calculateSum(int array[]){
    int center = array.length/2;
    int result = array[center-1]+array[center]+array[center+1];
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you trying to achieve on the above problem is this one.

```
public static int  isCentered(int [] arr) {
    int sum= 0;
    int expectedSum=15;
    int mid = arr.length/2;
    int len= arr.length;
    for (int i = 0;  i <len ; i++) {
        sum=arr[mid]+arr[mid+1+i]+arr[mid-1-i];
        if(sum==expectedSum){
            if ((len-3)%2==0){
                return 1;
            }else{
                return 0;
            }
        }else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* sampleData
* {3, 2, 10, 4, 1, 6, 9}
* {2, 10, 4, 1, 6, 9}
* {3, 2, 10, 4, 1, 6}
* {9, 15, 6}
* {15}
* {14}
*/

public class IsCentered15 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int[] sampleData = { 11 };
        int result = isCentered15(sampleData);

        System.out.println(result);

    }

    static int isCentered15(int[] a) {

        int returnValue = 0;
        int centeredIndex = 0;
        int sum = 0;

        if ((a.length % 2) == 0) {

            returnValue = 0;

        } else if (a.length == 1) {

            if (a[0] == 15) {
                returnValue = 1;
            } else {
                returnValue = 0;
            }

        } else {

            /*
             * as we know index start from 0, example a.length = 7 and center of index will
             * be index of 3. So int 7/2 = 3 *
             */

            centeredIndex = (a.length / 2);
            sum = a[centeredIndex - 1] + a[centeredIndex + 1] + a[centeredIndex];
            int centeredValue = a[centeredIndex];

            if (sum == 15 || centeredValue == 15) {

                returnValue = 1;

            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.